# How do I decode a JSON file containing arrays Swift 4?

Tags: json, swift

I have a JSON file which I'm trying to decode but am getting an error message:

> typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil))

My code is as follows:

```
struct Phrase: Decodable {
let sentences: [String]
}


func getFromJSON() {

    do {
        let jsonURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "script", withExtension: "json")
        let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
        let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: jsonURL!)
        let jsonSentence = try jsonDecoder.decode([Phrase].self, from: jsonData)
        debugPrint(jsonSentence)

    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

I've been looking at lots of other stack overflow questions and I've noticed that the format of these JSON files are different to mine. They are formatted as dictionaries while mine is like this-

```
[
["bin blue", "with A 2 soon"],
["set blue", "in A 9 soon"],
["lay blue", "at A 3 please"],
["3 5 zero zero 5 8"],
["place blue", "by A 6 now"],
["lay green", "at B ZERO now"],
["8 9 1 5 4 zero"]
]
```

I know that the decoder is looking for a dictionary but how do I have it decode the arrays instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need

```
let jsonSentence = try jsonDecoder.decode([[String]].self, from: jsonData)
```

Comment: +1. Hardy143, You can't use `struct Phrase` because JSON doesn't have a `sentences` key. Your JSON is an Array of Arrays.

Comment: @subdan exactly no keys here

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON data does not match the structure you want to parse. The JSON is an *array of string arrays*, whereas you try to parse an *array of `Phrase`* objects.

**Solution 1**: to keep the JSON structure as-is, you need to parse an array of arrays, or to keep the custom model type, by using a type alias:

```
typealias Phrase = [String]
```

**Solution 2**: to keep the `struct` you defined as-is, you'll have to change the JSON format to this;

```
[
  { "sentences": ["bin blue", "with A 2 soon"] },
  { "sentences": ["set blue", "in A 9 soon"] },
  ...
]
```

---

Both solutions will work with your `getFromJSON` implementation.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I went with solution 1 and works perfect.